# can't read Element.prototype in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, element, prototype

If I run this javascript:

```
var a,b=Element.prototype;
for(a in b)b[a];
```

Firefox gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Value does not implement interface Element.
```

Here is a test case:
http://codepen.io/WilliamMalo/pen/AJkuE

It works in all other browsers. How can I make it work in firefox? It's driving me nuts!

Comment: I don't get any error in firefox. May be it's in the older versions

Comment: It runs fine incase of function but It is giving errors in all values like id, tagName, etc. If you could tell explain us what you are trying to do we could suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The Firefox (and recent IE) behavior here is because the property getters for some properties (say `firstChild`) are on the prototype object bu the properties make no sense on the prototype itself.  Trying to get them on the prototype will throw.

This is the behavior required by the specification, in fact.  See http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/#dfn-attribute-getter step 2 substep 2 subsubstep 2.  Firefox and IE are following the spec here and WebKit-based browsers are not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
console.log('parentNode' in Element.prototype
   ? Element.prototype.parentNode
   : 'no parentNode here');
```

Pretty innocent, right? It gives you `no parentNode` string in Chrome (and probably in Safari too)... yet it fails *both* in Firefox (21) and IE (10):

- Firefox: `value does not implement interface Node`
- IE10:    `invalid calling object`

Why is that? See, we've entered the Host Objects Zone, also known as [**The Zone Of No Rules**](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/#host_objects_have_no_rules). The point is that while some properties seem to be attached to `Element.prototype`, they're inaccessible from there - only from `Element` instances.

What can be done about it? An obvious way out is wrapping the offender in 'try-catch' block:

```
var a, b = Element.prototype, arr = [];
for (a in b) {
  try {
    b[a];
    arr.push(a); 
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` in your loop instead of accessing each property directly using the key on the prototype: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/aJgcr

Comment: No, this won't work. For many properties (`id`, for example) `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` returns quite normal description object, yet attempt to access them will result in error.

Comment: @raina77ow - correct, that's because those native functions are hard bound to a specific localName internally, but that wasn't the OP's concern. William wanted a way to prevent failures from simply looping a prototype object, and Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor certainly does that ;)

Comment: I made an example of using Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() to iterate on a prototype http://codepen.io/WilliamMalo/pen/hfoFt please help me make it better, I'm sure this could be useful to other people, and I don't want them to copy and paste my ugly code.