# [clarification needed]How to handle typeerrors while exploring properties of prototypes

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I wanted to write a function to list all avalible properties (distinguish between functions and the remaining properties) of an object and its prototypes to get an overview how this object can be manipulated.

**Problem:** Can't acess certain !existing! properties of an object, see sample code at the end of the post, because the code is throwing type errors like this: "TypeError: [...] getter called on an object that does not implement interface [...]".

Exact errorcode for the example below: "TypeError: 'ownerGlobal' getter called on an object that does not implement interface EventTarget." The odd thing is that the property and the get&set functions exist, see: http://postimg.org/image/sh1okt4g7/ + `console.log("property exists: "+obj.hasOwnProperty(oneElem));` prints true.

While researching this problem I came across this post: [can't read Element.prototype in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865207/cant-read-element-prototype-in-firefox/16868369#16868369).

As I understand it all the typeErrors came from the fact that the different objectPrototypes in the prototype chain have no accessible values, because they are prototypes and no "real" objects. **Therefore all properties which throw TypeErrors schould be discarded, because they can't get used. Is that right?**
**On the other hand is it safe to assume that all the remaining properties can be used (invoking functions, reading values) altough they are defined by a prototype object?**

---

sourcecode:
 - not that interesting, but if someone want to test it out, feel free to do it
 - create a new firefox addon (developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)), copy&paste the code and run the addon

```
var mtabs = require("sdk/tabs");
//mtabs.open("http://lolvideoslol.tumblr.com/post/124427537261/lani-p-the-amount-of-pressure-put-on-the-last"); //open tab
mtabs.on('pageshow', newTabLoaded); //add listener
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core"); //convert to low lvl to get document


function newTabLoaded(tabHigh) {
    //get website doc
    var document = viewFor(tabHigh.window).top.gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(viewFor(tabHigh)).contentDocument;
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='video']"); //get interesting elements
    analysePrototypeChain(nodeList[0]); //analyse the first element
    //for (let i = 0, len = nodeList.length; i < len; i++) {
    //    analysePrototypeChain(nodeList[i]); //analyse the elements
    //}
}

/**
 * Prints the prototype chain and functions/other properties for the given object.
 *
 * @param {Object} obj to process.
 */
function analysePrototypeChain(obj) {
    console.log("##############################################################");
    console.log("######## checking prototypeChain for:", obj, "########");
    let formatOptions = {"newLines": 0, "toString": 1};
    printPrototypeChain(obj, [], formatOptions);
    console.log();
    let protos = getPrototypeChain(obj, []);

    for (let i = 0, len = protos.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (protos[i] == "[object EventTargetPrototype]") {
            console.log("_"+i+":", protos[i]);
            printProperties(protos[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log("##############################################################");

}


/**
 * Prints the complete prototype chain for the given object.
 *
 * @param {Object} obj to process.
 * @param {Array} stringArr must be empty when first called.
 * @param {Object} formatOptions to control the formatting of the output.
 * let formatOptions = {"newLines": 0, "toString": 1};
 */
function printPrototypeChain(obj, stringArr, formatOptions) {
    if (stringArr.length === 0) {
        if (formatOptions.toString === 1) {
            stringArr.push(obj+"");
        } else {
            stringArr.push(obj);
        }
    }

    let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    if (proto === null || proto === undefined) {
        if (formatOptions.newLines === 1) {
            stringArr.push("\n\n->");
        } else {
            stringArr.push("->");
        }

        if (formatOptions.toString === 1) {
            stringArr.push(proto+"");
        } else {
            stringArr.push(proto);
        }
        console.log.apply(console, stringArr);

    } else {
        if (formatOptions.newLines === 1) {
            stringArr.push("\n\n->");
        } else {
            stringArr.push("->");
        }

        if (formatOptions.toString === 1) {
            stringArr.push(proto+"");
        } else {
            stringArr.push(proto);
        }
        return printPrototypeChain(proto, stringArr, formatOptions);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns all prototypes in the prototype chain for the given object.
 *
 * @param {Object} obj to process.
 * @param {Array} stringArr must be empty when first called.
 * @returns {Array} Array with the determined prototypes.
 */
function getPrototypeChain(obj, stringArr) {
    if (stringArr.length === 0) {
        stringArr.push(obj)
    }

    let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    if (proto === null || proto === undefined) {
        stringArr.push(proto);
        return stringArr;
    } else {
        //if (proto == "[object EventTargetPrototype]") {
        //    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
        //        console.log(val + ' -> ' + obj[val]);
        //    });
        //}
        stringArr.push(proto);
        return getPrototypeChain(proto, stringArr);
    }
}


/**
 * Checks the given object for functions and other properties and prints them.
 *
 * @param {Object} obj to process.
 */
function printProperties(obj) {
    if (obj === undefined || obj === null || obj === NaN) {
        console.log(+"\n"+obj+" has no properties.");
        return;
    }
    //for further usage
    let functionList = [];
    let remainingPropertiesList = [];
    //output Strings
    let functionString = "";
    let remainingPropertiesString = "";
    //checks all properties and fills functionList and remainingPropertiesList before invoking the next instruction
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(checkElem);


    console.log("Properties for:",obj+"");
    let functionListLength = functionList.length;
    if (functionListLength > 0) {
        for (let i = 0, l = functionList.length-1; i < l; i++) {
            functionString += functionList[i].type+" "+functionList[i].name+"(), ";
        }
        functionString += functionList[functionList.length-1].type+" "+functionList[functionList.length-1].name+"()";
    }

    let remainingPropertiesListLength = remainingPropertiesList.length;
    if (remainingPropertiesListLength > 0) {
        for (let i = 0, l = remainingPropertiesList.length-1; i < l; i++) {
            remainingPropertiesString += "["+remainingPropertiesList[i].type+" "+remainingPropertiesList[i].name+"], ";
        }
        remainingPropertiesString += "["+remainingPropertiesList[remainingPropertiesList.length-1].type+" "+
            remainingPropertiesList[remainingPropertiesList.length-1].name+"]";
    }

    console.log(">>>"+functionList.length+" functions:\n"+functionString);
    console.log(">>>"+remainingPropertiesList.length+" remainingProperties:\n"+remainingPropertiesString);


    //iterates through all properties to determine their type
    function checkElem(oneElem, pos, arr) {
        console.log("pos: "+pos+" at "+obj+" is: "+oneElem); //actual pos at the encolsing object
        try {
            if ((typeof obj[oneElem]) === 'function') {
                functionList.push({type: (typeof obj[oneElem]), name: oneElem});
            } else {
                remainingPropertiesList.push({type: (typeof obj[oneElem]), name: oneElem});
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("<<<<<<<error while accessing "+oneElem);
            console.log("property exists: "+obj.hasOwnProperty(oneElem));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it all the typeErrors came from the fact that the different objectPrototypes in the prototype chain have no accessible values, because they are prototypes and no "real" objects.

Yes, prototype properties should not be *called* on the prototype objects themselves, they should be called on a concrete instance that has been created through a constructor.

As you can see in your screenshot `ownerGlobal` is not a value property, it is a getter, thus a function that would get called with the prototype as the `this` object, something that the getter function has not been designed for.

What you can do is getting the [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) on a prototype:

`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(somePrototype, propertyName)`, then you can extract the getter function and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) it to an instance